# How can i get the output of a function in the environment with an argument as name?

Tags: r, function, environment

I created a function with datasets as output.
I want the dataset in my environment but I can't get it done with an argument as name.

```
myfun <-  function(dfname) { 
dfname <<- df
}
myfun(df1)
```

The df above is created in the function and needs to be stored as df1 in the environment. But when I run the script the df is stored as "dfname".

Comment: This is very bad practice. Don't do it. Write a function that returns its result and assign outside the function. Anyway, it appears you are trying to create an inferior version of the `assign` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not recommended but this code works

```
myfun <-  function(dfname) { 
  assign(dfname, iris, pos =  1)
}
```

Test :

```
myfun("dfname")
head(dfname)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me!

Comment: If this answer was useful, please consider accepting it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
myfun <-  function(dfname) { 
  #dfname <<- df
  return(df)
}
df1 <- myfun(df1)
```

Comment: There are more than 30 datasets this way i need to use more than 30 extra lines of code. I want to store the datasets directly from the function.

Comment: @klaasberbee If this information is additional to your question then you should **edit your question:** https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48826897/edit

Comment: @klaasberbee, Put the datasets in a list and then return the list.